# Scope and method passing

Tags: swift

I have this defined within my class:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let sections = ["Design", "Development", "Mobile"]
    var blogPost1 = ["title" : "StackOverflow", "author" : "John Doe"]
    var blogPost2 = ["Getting started" : "title", "John" : "author"]
    var posts = [blogPost1, blogPost2]

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        var blogPosts = [blogPost1, blogPost2]
    }
}
```

I dont understand why I am able to create the blogPosts variable within `viewDidLoad` but not inside the class under blogPost2? If I try, Xcode won't autocomplete and return an error that says the ViewController doesn't have a member named "blogPost1". However I can create it within viewDidLoad() but I do not know how to use it within other functions.

Second issue:

I have a TableViewController. Within cellForRowAtIndexpath, I am trying send this message:

```
 var posts = blogPosts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
```

but objectAtIndex is not suggested in autocomplete. I'm sure it's a rookie mistake but I am lost. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second issue, **objectAtIndex** is a method of NSArray class, whereas the variable blogPosts you created is type of Array (of Swift).

Just use the subscript syntax:

```
var posts = blogPosts[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first problem is that initialize of properties with default values doesn't have access to `self` yet because the object is not yet completely initialized.  You need to move the initialization into your init method.

```
init() {
    blogPost1 = ["title" : "StackOverflow", "author" : "John Doe"]
    blogPost2 = ["Getting started" : "title", "John" : "author"]
    posts = [blogPost1, blogPost2]
}
```

Note also that you're inconsistent in your usage of keys and values, that's gonna bite you later.

As Oguz pointed out, your second problem is that you're trying to use an NSArray method on an Array, easiest to just use `blogPosts[indexPath.row]`  But, that probably won't work for you either since blogPosts isn't defined as a property it's defined as a local variable in the function.  You could use `posts[indexPath.row]`

Comment: Thank you! As for the inconsistent usage, I did it this way on purpose. I'm following a tutorial.